# tensorflow get tensor size but failed to initialize tf.Variable size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to use a placeholder to hold a list, and get the length of it. Then when I use it to initialize my variable, it give the error

following is a sample code to create the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
story_mask=[4,7,10,12,15]
input_feed={}
input_feed[a.name] = story_mask
b = tf.reshape(tf.shape(a), [])
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([b, b], -0.1, 0.1), name="l1_weights")
c = tf.matmul(a, weights)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(c,input_feed))
```

The Error message is at:

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([b, b], -0.1, 0.1), name="l1_weights")
```

and message is:

> TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected

Anyone has idea where I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: there are many errors in your code. What is the overlying task that you are trying to model with tensorflow ?

Comment: @fabrizioM Thank you. this is just a simplified code to reproduce my error. one part of my code is given a story, and I split it into many sentences. Based on number of sentences, I built a feedforward neural network. In that sense, the neural network weights dimension is determined by number of sentences. That is what I am trying to do

Comment: so you need a maximum size of the size of the sentence.  `a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[ SenteceMaxSize])`

Comment: @fabrizioM, Thank you. I tried that, still the same error, In the above example, I change `a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[10])` the Error is still the same: TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected